# How to make a picture clickable and then flip to a different picture? Android Studio

Tags: android, image

Like in the picture of this url ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/L18ox.jpg)  (which I do not own). So basically a touch command to flip the picture to a different picture and if it matches to stay flipped but if it does not match to flip back.

Can someone please help me out. I am new to this so sorry if I stepped on anyone's toes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GridView` and handle the `onClick` event for the grid items. There is [FlipAnimation (gitHub)](http://genzeb.github.io/flip/) which you can apply on the item in the `onClick` event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a frame layout and in the onClick() ,make the the first image Disappear and the second one appear.That will do.

Answer (score 0):

1.Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_front"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <!--add your front layout components-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <!--add your back layout components-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Animation class

```
    public class FlipAnimation extends Animation {
    private Camera camera;
    private View fromView;
    private View toView;
    private float centerX;
    private float centerY;
    private boolean forward = true;

    /**
     * Creates a 3D flip animation between two views.
     *
     * @param fromView First view in the transition.
     * @param toView   Second view in the transition.
     */
    public FlipAnimation(View fromView, View toView) {
        this.fromView = fromView;
        this.toView = toView;

        setDuration(700);
        setFillAfter(false);
        setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    /**
     * To reverse direction of flip animation
     */
    public void reverse() {
        forward = false;
        View switchView = toView;
        toView = fromView;
        fromView = switchView;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        centerX = width / 2;
        centerY = height / 2;
        camera = new Camera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        final double radians = Math.PI * interpolatedTime;
        float degrees = (float) (180.0 * radians / Math.PI);
        if (interpolatedTime >= 0.5f) {
            degrees -= 180.f;
            fromView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (forward)
            degrees = -degrees; //determines direction of rotation when flip begins

        final Matrix matrix = transformation.getMatrix();
        camera.save();
        camera.rotateY(degrees);
        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        camera.restore();
        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    }
}
```

3. A method to flip a view on user action.

```
public static void flipCard(View view) {
        View rootLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_root);
        View cardFace = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_front);
        View cardBack = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_back);
        FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(cardFace, cardBack);
        if (cardFace.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            flipAnimation.reverse();
        }
        rootLayout.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
    }
```

4. OnClick example.

```
Utility.flipCard(rootView//your root view here);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my new library [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) can help. It includes basic flip animation and extends `ViewFlipper`. I mean a fully customizable library where you will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation and shapes you desire (and much more), included the Gmail image flipping.

Please have a look.