# Android: Layout flip animation

Tags: android, animation, material-design, materialized-views

I am trying to develop a UI with animation (Android Native code). Here when when swipe left a new layout is going to visible as flip animation and when swipe down another layout is comes from top with flip animation

[Click here for the UI](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=52c86ffe6b&view=fimg&th=14f684bb5b245171&attid=0.1&disp=emb&realattid=ii_14e42dec57ffc9da&attbid=ANGjdJ9EdhQX0qth_iMruydKc9NuyEwIsQMV6nKR25c9Sf5P2_4dM6Td-Hk-H3gy4fibM6xOxPifZOWvVr3o6AjDLL5JQ9G0Qnth1Pj02eh629KFI2MOT8Km1b_26ck&sz=w532-h944&ats=1441078184802&rm=14f684bb5b245171&zw&atsh=1)

I made it by swipe listener when I swipe left and down the two layout going to visible, but it is not animated.

Can anyone tell how to add a animation like flip when we going to set a layout **visiblity** as **visible** from **gone** satge

Can anyone please tell me
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please check -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174836/how-to-make-a-picture-clickable-and-then-flip-to-a-different-picture-android-st/32175340#32175340

Comment: are you using ng-show or ng-hide?

Answer (score 0):

Check this : https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager

With this you can Swipe horizontally and vertically both

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using angular-material so you can animate your ng-hide/ng-show:

1. Import [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)
2. After you can animate `ng-show`
3. To conclude create your css animation or copy/paste from [animate.css repo](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

   ```
   /* when hiding the picture */

   .ng-hide-add {
       animation: 0.5s bounceOutDown ease;
   }


   /* when showing the picture */

   .ng-hide-remove {
       animation: 0.5s bounceInDown ease;
   }


   /* ANIMATIONS (FROM ANIMATE.CSS) ======================== */


   /* flip in */

   @keyframes bounceInDown {
       from,
       60%,
       75%,
       90%,
       to {
           animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
       }
       0% {
           opacity: 0;
           transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
       }
       60% {
           opacity: 1;
           transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
       }
       75% {
           transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
       }
       90% {
           transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
       }
       to {
           transform: none;
       }
   }

   @keyframes bounceOutDown {
       20% {
           transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
       }
       40%,
       45% {
           opacity: 1;
           transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
       }
       to {
           opacity: 0;
           transform: translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: oh sorry you used angular-material tag